# Is Thunderbolt on the same bus as FireWire and Ethernet on a late 2012 Mac Mini

Tags: mac-mini, thunderbolt, ethernet, firewire

I use a late 2012 Mac Mini as a music server. My expensive, external audio digital to analogue converter (DAC) was connected to the Mini by FireWire. After a lightning strike the Mac Mini FireWire and Ethernet ports do not work.

Is it likely that the Thunderbolt port is also burnt out. I am proposing to use a TB/FW adapter.

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

> After a lightning strike the Mac Mini FireWire and Ethernet ports do
>   not work.

The Mac mini got hit by lightening and still functions?  I am surprised that you only lost two ports

> Is it likely that the Thunderbolt port is also burnt out.

Likely, but it's  impossible to tell from this distance.  To know for certain, you need to plug in a device to test functionality.

> I am proposing to use a TB/FW adaptor.

This sounds like an excellent idea.  If you plug it in and it works/doesn't work then you have your diagnosis.

The only other suggestion other than trying things to see if it works is to run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.

However, it sounds like you lost some key functionality when the Ethernet port died.  It's probably a good time to take it in for service or upgrade to a newer model.

On a side note, a good (and cheap) bit of insurance is to get a UPS Back-Up Power Supply with surge protection.  I personally use [CyberPower UPSs](http://radnex.us/cyberpower-backup-ups-with-surge-protection) on all my Apple gear (APC everywhere else) because they are compatible with macOS.

Speaking from personal experience...in 25+ years in IT in the lightning capital of the US (Florida), I have been hit by lightning twice and never lost a single piece of gear.  I did lose two APC units to lightning strikes (both at work), but I never lost any equipment.